# Identity Server 4, Angular2 with .NET 4.6

Tags: .net, angular, identityserver4

I am looking for a simple code example that uses Identity Server 4 for authentication and a Angular2 front end (or any java script really!).

There are a few examples out there, BUT I need one that does **NOT** use Asp.Net Core,but rather uses .NET 4.6.*.

Does anybody know of a working code example which uses these technologies? Or is that not possible at all?

Comment: Just be glad it isn't core this question is a PITA there.

Comment: Just get a normal sample and change the target framework to net462. try this sample as a start. https://damienbod.com/2016/10/01/identityserver4-webapi-and-angular2-in-a-single-asp-net-core-project/